# Disable html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to test behaviour of website in case if browser doesn't support html5 canvas. So I need to disable canvas.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"> 
    <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
    <!-- I NEED TO GET HERE!!! -->
</canvas>
```

Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't disable canvas.

If you are doing this for testing purposes simply rename the canvas temporary:

```
<Xcanvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"> 
        <!-- Insert fallback content here -->
        <!-- I NEED TO GET HERE!!! -->
</Xcanvas>
```

Now the canvas won't be recognized.

The other option is to use an older browser such as IE8 or lower (but it will probably mess up the layout/CSS).

HTML5 Canvas is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas) though so IE8- family is your best shot.

Comment: Of course! I'll do this after some minutes, because it doesn't allow me to accept your answer right now.

Comment: There really should be a way to disable the canvas, and in fact, all HTML5 media functionality, both globally and per-site. For one thing, it would prevent canvas fingerprinting [⁽¹⁾](https://www.browserleaks.com/canvas) [⁽²⁾](https://panopticlick.eff.org/about#methodology) [⁽³⁾](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a simple paragraph inside the Canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"> 
<p>Canvas is not supported in this Browser :(</p>
</canvas>
```